# Convert all HTML Tags to lowercase

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this code, but PHP gives me an `Unknown modifier '?'` error.

Anyone knows what I did wrong? (I found the code on the internet, because I'm not familiar with regex)

```
$old = "<FONT></FONT><P></P><TR></TR>";
$newString = preg_replace("/</?\w+/e/", "strtolower('\\0')", $old);
echo $newString ."<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what you're looking for?

For posterity: this code will munge attributes comments and `<!CDATA[[]]!>`

```
<?php

function lowerTags($matches) {
    return strtolower($matches[1]);
}

$old = "<!--BLAH--><FONT COLOR='BLACK'>extra textCAPITALIZED</FONT><P></P><TR></TR>";

echo preg_replace_callback("/(<\/?[^!][^>]+)/", 'lowerTags', $old);
```

Comment: No I want all the text within a tag to be lowercase. So <TR> needs to be <tr> / </TR> => </tr> / <FONT COLOR='BLACK'> => <font color='black'>

Comment: so you want it to conver <FONT>ANNOYING CAPITALIZATION</FONT> to: <FONT>annoying capitalization</FONT>?

Comment: Ah yes. It works. Only 1 problem: <FONT COLOR="BLACK"> becomes <font color="BLACK"> could that be fixed?

Comment: do not use short tags ("<?"). It gives you no real benefit (save of 3 bytes ("<?" vs "<?php" does not really count) but short tag can be turned off in `php.ini` exposing your script code.

Comment: @AngeloA it should be noted that this will likely have unintented consequences if it used, as it will alter ALL attributes to be lowercase regardless of their prior usage. This will also break [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) in XML, and munge comments.

Comment: @Mythril that's fine! This code is needed to make is easier to find tags in a file without having to worry about in which case they're written. Thank you!

Comment: If you are on linux you could just use this command (subbing out PHP for target file extension): find -name "*.php" -print0|xargs -0 grep -i "SEARCHSTRING"

Comment: Does not work for 1 char tags, like <P>. Should use `(<\/?[^!>]+)`

Answer (score 5):

PHP *5.4* and earlier:

```
$old = "<FONT></FONT><P id='P1'></P><TR></TR>"; 
$newString = preg_replace("/(<\/?\w+)(.*?>)/e", "strtolower('\\1') . '\\2'", $old); 
echo $newString ."<br/>";
```

The `e` modifier is **deprecated** as of PHP *5.5.0*, use `preg_replace_callback` instead:

```
$old = "<FONT></FONT><P id='P1'></P><TR></TR>"; 
$newString = preg_replace_callback("/(<\/?\w+)(.*?>)/", function ($m) {
  return strtolower($m[1]) . $m[2]; }, $old); 
echo $newString ."<br/>";
```

---

Output:

```
<font></font><p id='P1'></p><tr></tr><br/>
```

Comment: @TadeuszMajkowski - Correct, use `preg_replace_callback` as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

replace regex `</?\w+>` with itself after apply lower case

Answer (score 0):

I don't use or recommend regex to parse html, but there are some mistakes here:

1. You are using the `/` symbol as a delimiter so you need to escape it in the regex or use another delimiter;
2. You have an extra `/` at the end that should not be there.

So your code should probably look something like (using another delimiter):

```
$newString = preg_replace("#</?\w+#e", "strtolower('\\0')", $old);
```

Comment: With this regex you are not sure if tag really has `>` behind or not

Comment: @Ωmega I would never use a regex to parse html, so I just corrected the errors, not the regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that handles attribute names as well as tags. Note this still isn't completely correct; it assumes the character > will never be found in an attribute value such as the alt text for an image. To do this correctly, use the DOMDocument class (but be aware that the parser will have problems with invalid input).

```
<?php

function lowercase_tag_name_callback(array $m) {
  return strtolower($m[1]) . lowercase_attribute_name($m[2]);
}
function lowercase_attribute_name_callback(array $m) {
  return ' ' . strtolower($m[1]) . $m[2];
}
// change each attribute name to lowercase
function lowercase_attribute_name($input) {
  $output = $input;
  $output = preg_replace_callback('# ([a-zA-Z]+)(="[^"]+")#', 'lowercase_attribute_name_callback', $output);
  $output = preg_replace_callback("# ([a-zA-Z]+)(='[^']+')#", 'lowercase_attribute_name_callback', $output);
  $output = preg_replace_callback('# ([a-zA-Z]+)(=[^"\']+[ >])#', 'lowercase_attribute_name_callback', $output);
  return $output;
}

$input = <<<'EOD'
<FONT></FONT><P id="P1"></P><TR></TR><IMG SRC="FourFive.jpg" ID='AnIDHere' ALT="FOUR five" CLASS=FourFive><!-- A Comment Here --><![CDATA[ CDATA Text Here ]]>

EOD;

$output = preg_replace_callback("#(</?\w+)(.*?>)#", 'lowercase_tag_name_callback', $input); 
print "BEFORE: $input";
print " AFTER: $output";
```